# React -> material-ui -> Autocomplete: problem to get a value from an API

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, api-platform.com

This is my first post on stackoverflow but not my first visit :) I apologize in advance if I make any mistakes or am incomplete in my request (and for my bad English...).

I created an API with api-platform. It's great. I then used api-platform/admin as the frontend. Everything works fine except for an autocomplete code.

I have to use an external API with a query. I can't use react-admin's autocompleteInput so I'm trying with material-ui.

The query of the API return that (with 20 objects):

```
{
"@context": "/contexts/Species",
"@id": "/v1/species/autocomplete",
"@type": "hydra:Collection",
"hydra:member": 
[
{
"@id": "/v1/species/0",
"@type": "Species",
"originId": 0,
"scientificName": "incertae sedis",
"family": null,
"status": "Synonyme"
},
{
"@id": "/v1/species/1",
"@type": "Species",
"originId": 1,
"scientificName": "Animalia",
"family": null,
"status": "Valide"
},
...
]
}
```

and my code is that:

```
const SpeciesAutocomplete = ({ id, label }) => {

const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("0");

React.useEffect(() => {

    dataProvider.getList('v1/species/autocomplete?query=' + query, {
        pagination: {},
        sort: {},
    })
        .then(({data}) => {
            setData(data);
        })
}, [query]);

return (
    <Autocomplete
        id={id}

        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue === null ? "0" : newValue.originId);
        }}

        options={data}

        inputValue={query}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
            setQuery(newInputValue);
        }}

        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => (option.originId  === value)}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => (option === null ? "" : option.scientificName  )}

        style={{ width: 300 }}
        loading={false}

        renderInput={(params) =>
            <TextField{...params}
                      label={label}
                      variant="outlined"
            />}
    />
);
```

But I cannot recover the value (id)...

Thank you and wish you a good weekend.

Comment: "But I cannot recover the value (id)" what `id`? The one you pass to `<Autocomplete id={id}`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it wasn't clear. No, the value={value} with newValue.originId. Thanks for the reply